# Stack must be clean before function epilogue confusion

Tags: c++, assembly, visual-studio-2008

I'm studying assembly language from the book ["Assembly Language Step-by-Step: Programming with Linux" by Jeff Dunteman](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Assembly-Language-Step-Step-Programming/dp/0470497025), and have come across an interesting paragraph in the book which I'm most likely misunderstanding, hence would appreciate some clarification on:

> "The stack must be clean before we destroy the stack frame and return control.  This simply means that any temporary values that we may have pushed onto the stack during the program’s run must be gone. All that is left on the stack should be the caller’s EBP, EBX, ESI, and EDI values.
>
> ...
>
> Once the stack is clean, to destroy the stack frame we must first pop the caller’s register values back into their registers, ensuring that the pops are in the correct order.
>
> ...
>
> We restore the caller’s ESP by moving the value from EBP into ESP, and finally pop the caller’s EBP value off the stack."

Consider the following code generated from Visual Studio 2008:

```
int myFuncSum( int a, int b)
{
001B1020  push        ebp  
001B1021  mov         ebp,esp 
001B1023  push        ecx       <------------------
    int c;
    c = a + b;
001B1024  mov         eax,dword ptr [ebp+8] 
001B1027  add         eax,dword ptr [ebp+0Ch] 
001B102A  mov         dword ptr [ebp-4],eax 
    return c;
001B102D  mov         eax,dword ptr [ebp-4] 
}
001B1030  mov         esp,ebp 
001B1032  pop         ebp  
001B1033  ret
```

The value of ecx (indicated), pushed to make space on the stack for my variable c, is, as far as I can see, only gone from the stack when we reset ESP; however, as quoted, the book states that the stack must be clean **before** we reset ESP.  Can someone please clarify whether or not I am missing something?

Comment: There are several books by that name. Please name the author and link to the book on Amazon.

Comment: Yes, apologies.  Its the one by Jeff Dunteman: http://www.amazon.co.uk/Assembly-Language-Step-Step-Programming/dp/0470497025

Comment: I meant in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The example from Visual Studio 2008 doesn't contradict the book. The book is covering the most elaborate case of a call. See the [x86-32 Calling Convention](http://unixwiz.net/techtips/win32-callconv-asm.html) as a cross-reference which spells it out with pictures.

In your example, there were no caller registers saved on the stack, so there are no `pop` instructions to be performed. This is part of the "clean up" that must occur before `mov esp, ebp` that the book is referring to. So more specifically, let's suppose the callee is saving `si` and `di` for the caller, then the prelude and postlude for the function might look like this:

```
push  ebp        ; save base pointer
mov   ebp, esp   ; setup stack frame in base pointer
sub   esp, 4     ; reserve 4 bytes of local data
push  si         ; save caller's registers
push  di

; do some stuff, reference 32-bit local variable -4(%ebp), etc
;   Use si and di for our own purposes...

; clean up

pop   di          ; do the stack clean up
pop   si          ;   restoring the caller's values
mov   esp, ebp    ; restore the stack pointer
pop   ebp
ret
```

In your simple example, there were no saved caller registers, so no final `pop` instructions needed at the end.

Perhaps because it's simpler or faster, the compiler elected to do the following instruction in place of `sub  esp, 4`:

```
push  ecx
```

But the effect is the same: reserve 4 bytes for a local variable.

Comment: OK, that link is helpful.  Thanks.  Yes, there are no registers pushed onto the stack in my example to save their state. But the book clearly states "The stack must be clean" and "All that is left on the stack should be the caller’s EBP, EBX, ESI, and EDI values".  **I clearly have the ECX left on the stack though!**  Your example doesn't have the temporary created by pushing ECX.
Does the "cleaning" of the stack by popping things off only apply hence to the registers whose state we explicitly want to save the state of?

Comment: Aren't you missing the final `pop ebp`, Lurker? This is confusing because the `push ecx` is not intended to save `ecx`, but to reserve space for a local variable - a (shorter) substitute for `sub esp, 4`. Bad example, Jeff!

Comment: @Wad the word "clean" is a bit funny here and it depends upon where you're at in the sequence. What's left on the stack, before I pop them off in this case are the caller's `si` and `di`. I think the wording in the text from the book are a bit confusing unless they're showing an example.

Comment: I should state that the code I posted above **wasn't** part of Jeff's book; I was just analysing it then applying what the book said, which is where I met my confusion.

Comment: @Wad that's good to point out, but I did understand that. It's actually a good example of the tailoring that occurs when not all the aspects of the stack frame are needed for a specific function.

Answer (score 0):

Notice the instruction:

```
push        ebp  
mov         ebp,esp   ; <<<<=== saves the stack base pointer
```

and the instruction:

```
mov         esp,ebp   ;  <<<<<== restore the stack base pointer 
pop         ebp
```

So after this sequence the stack is clean again

Comment: Thanks, but I already know this...my point was that it contradicts what the book says about the stack having to be clean **before** this is called...

Comment: I don't think it contradicts the book: "The stack must be clean before we destroy the stack frame and return control" means that when you do RET, the CPU finds the return address on the top of the stack.  The restoring of the stack base pointer is the mean to clean the stack.   The poping back of the registers here is not needed, because  ecx was not modified.

Comment: The interesting thing to note though is that if we didn't "reset" ESP to the value held in EBP, the "pop" would in fact act on the temporary that we created by pushing ECX, since that is in fact at the top of stack **until** we reset ESP...